# Is hint for translator compulsory while internationalizing a string containing variables?

Tags: plugin-development, translation, localization, language

I am following [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/) official guide to internationalise my plugin. But I am confused if the hints are must required incase of variables inside string?

```php
printf(
    /* translators: 1: Name of a city 2: ZIP code */
    __( 'Your zip code is %2$s, and your city is %1$s.', 'my-plugin' ),
    $city,
    $zipcode
);
```

Also in this documentation, no where it is mentioned to use `load_plugin_textdomain` to load the text domain. It is only mentioned about the `Domain Path`. So can I omit `load_plugin_textdomain` if I use `Domain Path`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notes to translators aren't *required*, as far as I can tell, but they will definitely help anyone out who's trying to translate your plugin. You might want to think of them as *best practices* rather than *requirements*.

As to your second question:

> Since WordPress 4.6 translations now take translate.wordpress.org as priority and so plugins that are translated via translate.wordpress.org do not necessary require load_plugin_textdomain() anymore. If you don’t want to add a load_plugin_textdomain() call to your plugin you have to set the Requires at least: field in your readme.txt to 4.6.
> — from [the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/#loading-text-domain)

So I gather that, if you intend your plugin to be translated by the community at [translate.wordpress.org](https://translate.wordpress.org/), you don't need to call `load_plugin_textdomain()`. However, if you're not going to be distributing your plugin through [the official WordPress repository](https://wordpress.org/plugins/) (eg, you'll be using GitHub or your personal site to distribute it), you might still need to `load_plugin_textdomain()`.